# Безопасная песочница для запуска powershell cкриптов

Tags: c#, powershell

Хочу сделать песочницу для powershell скриптов, в связи с чем вопрос: возможно ли ограничить список доступных для выполнения командлетов, чтобы избежать нежелательных действий со стороны пользователей? Песочницу планирую написать на C# (Будет работать через веб)

Comment: Да, если можно, точнее если сами пишете зачем добавлять поддержку ненужных функций?)

Answer (score 0):

да. попробуйте использовать секцию [Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_data_sections)